# SPOJ ETF c/c++ code

Tags: c++

I am doing a question in spoj http://www.spoj.com/problems/ETF/ . I submitted this code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int fi(int);
int main()
 {
    int t,n;
     cin>>t;
     while(t--)
     {
      cin>>n;
      printf("%d\n",fi(n));

     }
  }   
 int fi(int n) 
 { 
   int result = n; 
   for(int i=2;i*i <= n;i++) 
   { 
     if (n % i == 0) result -= result / i; 
     while (n % i == 0) n /= i; 
   } 
   if (n > 1) result -= result / n; 
   return result; 
 }
```

ACCEPTED IN: 0.60 sec.

I want to know one thing

1. Why my code got accepted in c++4.3.2 while i was using a printf?

Comment: It's a bug in that version of gcc.

Comment: so can we use scanf and cout also?

Comment: If you feel like exploiting bugs in ancient gcc releases that are fixed in subsequent releases, then go ahead. Not my cup of tea.

Comment: accepted in 0.28 sec using scanf :)

Comment: Sometimes functions will work without including the specific header, but you should never rely on that behavior and always include what you need for what you are using.  I think that's what you were asking, but it seems very unclear.

Comment: You can use `printf` and `scanf` in C++. You just need to include an appropriate header, either `<cstdio>` or `<stdio.h>`. The gcc bug lets you get away without including one of these. It makes no sense whatsoever to exploit the bug when you can just use the functions absolutely legally.